# Непонятный отступ

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Делаю сайт на bootstrap. Создал модальное окно. При открытии модального окна всё нормально. При закрытии справа появляется непонятный отступ padding-right. При открытии и закрытии повторно этот отступ увеличивается и так он может увеличиваться до бесконечности.

```
   <p align="right">  <button class="btn btn-success " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
              Заказать звонок
            </button>
            </p>

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Форма заявки</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <ul align="center" style="list-style-type: none">
                            <label>Имя</label>
                          <li> <input type="text" name="name" id="name1" placeholder="Введите своё имя"><li>
                                <li> <label>Номер телефона</label><li>
                                <li>   <input type="text" name="number_phone" id= "number_phone1" placeholder="Введите свой телефон"><li>
                                <li> <label>Емели</label><li>
                                <li>  <input type="email" name="email" id="email1" placeholder="Введите свою почту"><li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Подтвердить</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: и что понятно по разметке ? нету стилей , поправьте код так что бы он воспроизводился в сниппете

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the pag"https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
     <p align="right">  <button class="btn btn-success " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
              Заказать звонок
            </button>
            </p>

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Форма заявки</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <ul align="center" style="list-style-type: none">
                            <label>Имя</label>
                          <li> <input type="text" name="name" id="name1" placeholder="Введите своё имя"><li>
                                <li> <label>Номер телефона</label><li>
                                <li>   <input type="text" name="number_phone" id= "number_phone1" placeholder="Введите свой телефон"><li>
                                <li> <label>Емели</label><li>
                                <li>  <input type="email" name="email" id="email1" placeholder="Введите свою почту"><li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Подтвердить</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Всё нормально отображается